# 6800 FC to R 8000 FC upgrade

Tags: road-bike, shimano, chainring, derailleur-front

I would like to replace my 6800 FC 52/36 and 6800 FD with the R8000 FD and FC 52/36. I'd like to utilize my existing 6800 brifters, which operate flawlessly.

Are the cable pull on the brifters (6800 vs 8000) identical such that the 0.4 mm difference in chainring spread between the listed chainsets will be dealt with by way of a new 8000 FD?

Comment: I believe you could get some .4mm spacers made to compensate for the difference. A thick metal can could be the right material.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, all Shimano 11-speed road cable pull is the same.

The long armed 11-speed FDs like FD-5800, 6800 etc can all be and frequently are replaced with the toggle models, i.e. FD-R8000.

Comment: My roadie has the opposite of your proposal: R8000 brifters, perfectly meshed with the R6800 crankset and front der.  No probs.